# Independent and dependent clauses classification

Tags: complex-sentences, dependent-clause, independent-clauses

"*What you see is what you get*". In this sentence, there are two noun clauses: 1. *What you see*, and 2. *What you get*. Obviously enough, it's a complex sentence. I want to know which one is the independent clause, and which one dependent?

Comment: No! "What you see" and "what you get" are not clauses but noun phrases in fused relative constructions. Compare "The thing that you see is the thing that you get".

Comment: @BillJ Phrases don't have a subject and predicate. Here, both group of words have a subject and predicate each. How can they be phrases?

Comment: The first NP "What you see" ("the thing that you see") is the subject, and the second NP "what you get" ("the thing that you get") is the subject complement. Are you familiar with fused relative constructions?

Comment: @BillJ No. But how can a phrase have subject-predicate combination?

Comment: It doesn't have a subject-predicate structure. In "the thing that you see", "thing" is head of the NP, and "that you see" is a relative clause modifying "thing". The whole expression can't be a clause because it has no main verb. Okay now?

Comment: @BillJ In regular grammar courses, especially up to senior secondary level, these topics are not taught. At what level are they taught? Is it what is called linguistics?

Comment: Any basic grammar course will make it clear that this sentence doesn't have an independent clause and a dependent clause. It has exactly the same basic construction as *might is right*, in which neither *might* nor *right* can be an independent clause or a dependent clause.

Comment: @JasonBassford So is it a simple sentence then?

Comment: I would say so, yes. At least if I were going by the common categories.

Comment: No: strictly speaking, it's not a simple sentence because it contains two embedded relative clauses as modifiers of the 'fused' heads "what". Relative clauses are, of course, subordinate (dependent) clauses.The main clause is the sentence as a whole. I've posted an answer with a tree diagram, which should make things clearer.

Comment: Oh, my goodness. How on earth did this get a close vote, yet alone two?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Tree Diagram of 'fused' relative construction, showing that both the subject and the predicative complement are NPs containing an embedded relative clause.

The pronoun "what" functions simultaneously as head of the NPs and object (in pre-nuclear position) in the relative clauses.

Comment: Many thanks @BillJ for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @user343802 You're welcome. I realise it's a complex tree --  in fact it's quite advanced grammar -- but it does help to show that there is an NP (noun phrase) each side of the main verb "is", one serving as the subject and the other as complement  of "is". The 'fusion' is in the word "what", which serves simultaneously as head (main word) and the relativised element in the modifying relative clause.

Comment: +1 How did you make that tree?!

Comment: @Araucaria Are you around?

Comment: @Araucaria   It's a bit fiddly --  'a work-around', really. Shall I email you?

Comment: @Araucaria Done. Something I forgot to mention in my email: To copy the Word document, you have to use the mouse to highlight it and then paste into Paint. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, Bill. I'm away from my computer at the mo. Will check my email, and start playing when I get back!